# LEFT OUTER JOIN Postgresql

Tags: postgresql

I have table invoice_items :

```
CREATE TABLE invoice_items
    (
     "id" varchar, 
     "invoice_id" varchar, 
     "type" varchar, 
     "current_balance" numeric(19) default 0,   
     "record_id" integer, 
     "created_date" timestamp, 
     "trx" integer, 
     "external_key" varchar, 
     "tenant_record_id" bigint
    );
```

then table invoice :

```
create table invoice
(
    id_invoice   bigint,
    uid_invoice  varchar(50),
    datetime     timestamp,
    description  text,
    amount       integer,
    eeuser       bigint,
    external_key varchar(30),
    tenant       "char",
    trx          "char",
    kb_invoice   varchar(50),
    document     bigint,
    sms          bigint,
    cur_balance  bigint default 0
);
```

Data on table invoice_items :

```
INSERT INTO invoice_items
    ("id","invoice_id",
    "type",
    "current_balance",
    "record_id",
    "created_date",
    "trx",
    "external_key",
    "tenant_record_id")
VALUES
('35f52412-65d8-4cf2-a9c5-5044a137f57c','bb963c3a-6fdb-47df-b3d9-bfa44f9b2ee1','USAGE','957','12977236','2019-12-18 18:46:56.432000','2','MT80','7')
,
('6cf749e0-43dd-47bc-a377-330ef92c28fb','bb963c3a-6fdb-47df-b3d9-bfa44f9b2ee1','ITEM_ADJ','958','12977262','2019-12-18 18:47:04.208000','3','MT80','7'
);
```

Data on table invoice :

```
INSERT INTO invoice
    ("kb_invoice",
      "trx",
    "id_invoice",
     "uid_invoice",
    "datetime",
    "cur_balance",
    "description",
    "eeuser",
    "external_key",
    "tenant",
    "document",
    "sms",
    "amount")
VALUES
('bb963c3a-6fdb-47df-b3d9-bfa44f9b2ee1','2','3012577', null,'2019-12-18 18:46:57.048000','957',null,'1236165','MT80','2078698','2',null,'1'
);
```

table invoice_items is used by API and table invoice used by another application called B, where B hit API the API generate 2 row on database with trx 2 and 3 have same invoice_id, and return to B give the invoice_id but some case application B failed to insert trx 3 so i want to insert missing data from failed insert on application B. What i think is i can find the missing value with this way :

From two table do left outer join to get null value where data on table invoice_items is exist but on table invoice not yet exist, the exist data from invoice_items i want to insert to table invoice on the example on table invoice missing data is the with `trx 3` and kb_invoice `'bb963c3a-6fdb-47df-b3d9-bfa44f9b2ee1'`. I try with this query to get the null data :

```
SELECT b.type, b.invoice_id, i.kb_invoice, b.current_balance, b.external_key, b.created_date, i.trx
from invoice_items b 
  left outer join invoice i ON b.invoice_id = i.kb_invoice 
where b.external_key='MT80' 
  and b.tenant_record_id='7'
```

but i get empty query from that query, any advice ?

the final result on table invoice have 2 record i have try with fidle : [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=1a9dcf02a513709b4a7be5309c880a7e)

> I have edited the fiddle and add some example data, but not work, the exist data from 2 table are show, like on the fiddle last data should be not show

Comment: So you want to search for all invoice-items with external_key 'MT80', where no invoice can be found?

Comment: Both invoice items have the same invoice_id so obviously the left join matches for both rows. If you had used an inner join, you'd get the same result (and both rows have the same tenant_record_id and external_key). Which of the two rows would you expect to be returned?

Comment: yes, get value just on invoice not exist but in invoice_items is exist @aschoerk

Comment: See my answer, that should work

Answer (score 0):

In your fiddle you have not kb_invoce with  null value so  your query return  no rows .. you need a proper null value for invoce kb_invoice

```
INSERT INTO invoice
("kb_invoice",
  "trx",
"id_invoice",
 "uid_invoice",
"datetime",
"cur_balance",
"description",
"eeuser",
"external_key",
"tenant",
"document",
"sms",
"amount")
VALUES
(null,'2','3012577', null,'2019-12-18 18:46:57.048000','957',null,'1236165','MT80','2078698','2',null,'1'
);
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=0029b3b397a64044484bf5ce87779011

Comment: I think you misunderstood what OP is trying to do. He is looking for orphaned `invoice_items`, but in his example both records in that table have matching record in `invoice`, so it returns 0 records. There is no need for NULL value in that column, he just needs to change that key value slightly in one of the tables. NULL qualifies, but is not the only possibility like you imply.

Answer (score 0):

try

**select * from (** SELECT b."type", b."invoice_id", i."kb_invoice" **as "a"**, b."current_balance", b."external_key", b."created_date", i."trx"
from invoice_items b 
  left outer join invoice i ON b."invoice_id" = i."kb_invoice" 
where b."external_key"='MT80' 
  and b."tenant_record_id"='7'**) as x 
  where x."a" is null;**

Comment: It is not possible to use column alias name in WHERE/ON clause. Not in PostgreSQL.

Comment: So use the left outer join as temporary result

Comment: I have try it, but the result if on 2 table is exist are show, it must not show
second row and third row should be not show, any advice ?

and with you example the result is empty @aschoerk

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=e0897bd52a27982725695cbd85bac6ce

Comment: Your testdata does not contain orphaned invoice_items, therefore the statement does not return any records. Did I understand your intentions wrong?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to find invoice items where there is no matching invoice row.

Your query looks fine, however your sample data doesn't actually convey the scenario that you say that you are looking for.

If you change your sample data `invoice_id` to reference a non-existent invoice (I've used `bb963c3a-6fdb-47df-b3d9-000000000000`), you'll see that your query does work, as per this [updated fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=a9d1ac5e067d7d72e43cad0be3e50cf4). The orphaned `invoice_item` row is returned, with null data in the parent which has been `left outer joined`. (You might have intended however to use `b.trx` in your select columns, i.e. off `invoice_items`, since `invoice.trx` will always be null).

However, it is fairly unusual to have a non-referentially enforced parent-child relationship, allowing for insertion of child items (`invoice item`) without an associated parent (`invoice`) row. This will be prone to orphaned rows (as per your query).

Answer (score 0):

This problem was success with this solution, on where clause add `trx = 3` because `trx = 3` is missing on table invoice but same invoice_id is exist on both table :

```
SELECT *
FROM invoice_items b
WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT *
                 FROM invoice i
                 WHERE i.kb_invoice = b.invoice_id and i.trx='3')
  and b."external_key" = 'MT80'
  and b."tenant_record_id" = '7'
  and b.type='ITEM_ADJ'
```

[Solution](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=33e15cb7f161e6b35d46ab47fce386ba)